# Constellation of 8-PSK modulation "undefined variable hmod"

Tags: matlab, simulation

Hello I was doing an example on a book and the code is the following, but its showing me an

> error in line 4:
>
> 'undefined variable "hMod" or class "hMod.Constellation".

Could someone help me find out how to fix it?:

```
%Modulacion 8PSK
%Grafica de dispersion
scatterPlot = comm.ConstellationDiagram('SamplesPerSymbol',1,...
'Constellation',hMod.Constellation);
%Grafica de constelacion
scatterPlot.PlotSettings.Constellation = 'on';
scatterPlot.PlotSettings.ConstellationStyle = 'rd';
% Add symbol labels
hold on;
k=log2(hMod.M);
for jj=1:hMod.M
    text(real(hMod.Constellation(jj))-0.15,...,
        imag(hMod.Constellation(jj))+0.15,...
        dec2base(hMod.SymbolMapping(jj),2,k));
end
hold off;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constellation for 8-PSK Modulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58465787/constellation-for-8-psk-modulation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get indicates that `hMod` is not known. In some cases you could get this message if you lack the required Toolbox. Considering the code you posted, hMod almost certainly a struct containing your input data. It is never loaded from a mat file or initialized, that part of the example is missing. Maybe check the previous pages for other code mentioning `hMod`

In case you where looking for a working example of such a diagram, take a look at the documentation: https://de.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/comm.constellationdiagram-system-object.html